# zendesk Xamarin binding for IPS and Android

Tags: xamarin, zendesk

I went through the documentation for doing Xamarin binding for Zendesk SDK for IOS. The documentation takes us through the scenario where we create .a file and proceed with binding. Zendesk library is provided in the form of a framework and though the Xamarin documentation says that frameworks contain .a file, I still could not find .a file in Zendesk framework. Hence, I am kind of blocked here. Any pointers here?

Link to Zendesk Library : https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_sdk_ios
Link to Xamarin documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=vsmac

I ran objective sharpie command. Though it says binding is done, it did not generate apidefinition.cs and structsAndEnums.cs file . Following is the output I see in terminal.

C02VX2ZCHTD6:~ naveen.ramachandrapp$ sharpie bind -output=Zen -namespace=zen  -sdk iphoneos11.3 -framework /Users/naveen.ramachandrapp/Downloads/zendesk_sdk_ios-masterObjectiveC/ZendeskSDK/4.1/ZendeskProviderSDK.framework
Parsing 1 header files...

Binding...
  [write] ApiDefinitions.cs
  [write] StructsAndEnums.cs

Binding Analysis:
  Automated binding is complete, but there are a few
  APIs which have been flagged with [Verify]
  attributes. While the entire binding should be
  audited for best API design practices, look more
  closely at APIs with the following Verify attribute
  hints:

MethodToProperty (30 instances):
    An Objective-C method was bound as a C# property
    due to convention such as taking no parameters and
    returning a value (non-void return). Often methods
    like these should be bound as properties to
    surface a nicer API, but sometimes false-positives
    can occur and the binding should actually be a
    method.

StronglyTypedNSArray (25 instances):
    A native NSArray* was bound as NSObject[]. It
    might be possible to more strongly type the array
    in the binding based on expectations set through
    API documentation (e.g. comments in the header
    file) or by examining the array contents through
    testing. For example, an NSArray* containing only
    NSNumber* instances can be bound as NSNumber[]
    instead of NSObject[].

ConstantsInterfaceAssociation (2 instances):
    There's no foolproof way to determine with which
    Objective-C interface an extern variable
    declaration may be associated. Instances of these
    are bound as [Field] properties in a partial
    interface into a nearby concrete interface to
    produce a more intuitive API, possibly eliminating
    the 'Constants' interface altogether.

PlatformInvoke (3 instances):
    In general P/Invoke bindings are not as correct or
    complete as Objective-C bindings (at least
    currently). You may need to fix up the library
    name (it defaults to '__Internal') and return/
    parameter types manually to conform to C calling
    conventionsfor the target platform. You may find
    you don't even want to expose the C API in your
    binding, but if you do, you'll probably also want
    to relocate the definition to a more appropriate
    class and expose a stronger type-safe wrapper. For
    P/Invoke guidance, see http://www.mono-project.com/
    docs/advanced/pinvoke/.

Once you have verified a Verify attribute, you
  should remove it from the binding source code. The
  presence of Verify attributes intentionally cause
  build failures.

For more information about the Verify attribute
  hints above, consult the Objective Sharpie
  documentation by running 'sharpie docs' or visiting
  the following URL:

```
http://xmn.io/sharpie-docs
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misread the documentation. It clearly lists 3 *different* scenarios:

> Generally in the iOS ecosystem you can find libraries in 3 flavors:
>
> As a precompiled static library file with .a extension together with
>   its header(s) (.h files). For example, Google’s Analytics Library
>
> As a precompiled Framework. This is just a folder containing the static
>   library, headers and sometimes additional resources with .framework
>   extension. For example, Google’s AdMob Library.
>
> As just source code files. For example, a library containing just .m and .h Objective C
>   files.

So you can create binding libraries using a `.a` file ***or*** a precompiled `.framework` (your case) ***or*** using `.h` and `.m` files. No need to look for `.a` files in the `.framework` file.

You can use objective sharpie to help create a ApiDefinition.cs file for your binding like so:

```
sharpie bind -framework ZendeskCoreSDK.framework -sdk iphoneos11.1
```

There is *loads* of documentation for Objective Sharpie here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/

Comment: I ran the sharpie command to generate bindings but though it completes without any errors in terminal, I do not see APIDefinition.cs and Srtuct.enum.cs file.